# I'm getting a operator undefined error when I use ||

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the code to check if an input either has nothing and is entered or doesn't have either Y or N, but I keep getting an error.

I've tried using just " | " but that doesn't work, and " , " just doesn't make sense.

```
while (answerToFirstQuestionYN.isEmpty() && !answerToFirstQuestionYN.equalsIgnoreCase("Y" || "N")) {
            System.out.println("Input not recognized, try again.");
            answerToFirstQuestionYN = reader.next();
        }
```

The error message is " The operator "||" is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String "

Comment: That is correct.  The `||` operator is only applicable to `boolean` (and in some cases `Boolean`) operand expressions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `||` operator can only join boolean expressions. So you need to separate the conditions to:

```
!(answerToFirstQuestionYN.equalsIgnoreCase("Y") ||
  answerToFirstQuestionYN.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
```

Your first condition (`answerToFirstQuestionYN.isEmpty()`) needs to be removed, otherwise the whole condition is only true if the string is empty.

Answer (score 3):

Java is not natural language. In English, we can say "if answer is Y or N", where "or" can join noun phrases. In Java, "or" only applies to truth values; and expressions are evaluated as in math, with whatever is in parentheses first. `answer.equals("Y" || "N")` would try to evaluate `"Y" or "N"` first, which is, from Java's perspective, nonsense. What you really need to do is to first have two truth values: "if answer is Y, or if answer is N":

```
answer.equals("Y") || answer.equals("N")
```